# Is there any way to make the blend-mode rule to work in tandem with CSS animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, mix-blend-mode

I'm encountering an issue when I try to apply the animation CSS rule in tandem with the blend mode.

If I'm using the `mix-blend-mode` without the animation rule (`animation: 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s 1 normal both running alpha_buildIn;`) everything is working fine, I'm not sure why maybe I'm doing something wrong or might be an issue.

In my example, I've used a keyframe to define the CSS animation which later is going to be applied to the parent element which had the image context where I'm using the `mix-blend-mode: color` rule.

I bet on `animation-fill-mode` `both` could cause the issue but I'm not sure why.

All help is appreciated!

```css
@keyframes alpha_buildIn {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);}

    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes alpha_buildIn {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-opacity: 1;
    }
}

.wrapper {
    width: 580px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgb(218, 39, 39);
    transform: scale(2.81724);
    transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
}

.element {
    animation: 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s 1 normal both running alpha_buildIn;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://d1az8j93w0r5an.cloudfront.net/assets/media/8oxrr);
    mix-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need vendor prefixes for [opacity](https://caniuse.com/css-opacity) or [transform](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

Comment: When I run this snippet, I see a flash of red and then immediately thereafter an image of a woman appears.  Can you clarify the intended/desired behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ?

Comment: The animation is an alpha CSS transition. 
The animation should play between multiple elements, if I'm adding a new element div the transition will be applied from the beginning of the first div element and to the end when the animation is done and the animation-direction is normal

When the animation is playing it's flashing from the animation CSS rule but also the image div it's using `mix-blend-mode: color;` which is not applied in tandem with the animation transition. If I'm removing the animation everything it's working properly. Regarding the image is big that's why is loading slow

Comment: I want to keep the blend mode during the animation, right now it's showing at the beginning and that's it if I remove the `animation-fill-mode both` it's showing at the beginning then is removed and it's showing again at the end when the animation is done but the blend mode it's not remaining persistent during the animation